# How to see if an iphone is synced if an NTP server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ntp

I am coding in Xcode 6.1.1 with objective-c.
In my app it is critical that I use the correct time.
I only want the app to use the time of the device when the time is synced with the servers.
If an user is somehow using his/her own "weird" time the app should detect that and tell the user to switch back to use the app.

I know there is `NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification`, but that only gives back when the time is changed. It does not give back what the change was and if the user switched to "custom" time or synced back to an NTP server.

Question: How do I detect if an user is connected to an NTP server or not?

Comment: You can't. Your only option is to verify the current time against an NTP server.

Comment: Ok that is simple and clear ;) Do you know some good NTP servers I can use?

Comment: A quick Google search will turn up plenty of public NTP servers.

Comment: Of course that is true, but Google does not give me the findings of one another ;) but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Maddy is right that you can't specifically find this out from iOS.

However, in the past I've delivered a client for a premium subscription service that had a similar need to know if the user was messing with time.  In particular we needed to verify this when there was no network available, in order to prevent the user from accessing premium content after their subscription had lapsed.  The very simple mechanism we used was as follows (IIRC):

1. every time the app launches or comes in from the background, record the current time (eg: in NSUserDefaults)
2. compare the current time to the last recorded time--if the current time is earlier than the last recorded time, force the user to go online and sign in to the service.

I don't claim it is 100% foolproof, but for our purposes we felt it was good enough to prevent users from trying to circumvent time-based restrictions on accessing premium content.

Comment: That is true, but it would be very handy if Apple provided some sort of service has asked above, but thanks anyway. Oh, and do you have some good findings with some NTP API's (if you used any of course).

Comment: I don't know exactly what problem you're trying to solve so thought that might be an alternative.  You're going to have to be creative with whatever you end up doing.  As far as time goes, we used the "Date" header in the http response from our own webservices.  Then we just had to make sure those servers were synched to an NTP service.